# WFS save problem, 'read-only' exception

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wfs

I am trying to save changes via WFS-T using GeoServer:

```
var editLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Edit Layer", {
        visibility: false,
        strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX(), saveStrategy],
        rendererOptions: { zIndexing: true },
        projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
        protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
            srsName: "EPSG:900913",
            url: URL,
            featureType: "SETTLEMENTS",
            featureNS: NS,
            featurePrefix: Prefix,
            geometryName: "GEOM",
            version: "1.1.0"
        }),
        eventListeners: ...
```

But the server returns error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ows:ExceptionReport version="1.0.0"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows http://../geoserver/schemas/ows/1.0.0/owsExceptionReport.xsd"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows">
  <ows:Exception exceptionCode="NoApplicableCode">
    <ows:ExceptionText>{http://...}SETTLEMENTS is read-only</ows:ExceptionText>
  </ows:Exception>
</ows:ExceptionReport>
```

Why is the feature readonly and how to fix it?

Comment: what sort of data source is underlying your layer?

Comment: @iant, Oracle database with SDO_GEOMETRY to store geometry data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: i had no [PK on that table](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gis.geoserver.user/21492). 
To add it to existing table with records used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944499/how-add-a-primary-key-autoincremented-on-my-existing-table).

Answer (score 2):

The most likely problem is that the user that is running GeoServer doesn't have write permission to the table (or one of the support metadata tables). If you are running inside Tomcat then there is (or should be) a tomcat user running the process who will almost certainly not have write permissions to the tables.

Comment: Yes, im using tomcat. Sorry, didnt mentioned that before. I was given the virtual machine with everything preinstalled, so dont know all the bones. Thank you for the answer, will check it tommorow morning, but think you're right. Also thank you for edit.

Comment: on geoserver in stores i have a 'map' user and in oracle ive granted all priviledges on the table i want edit/insert geometry. But nothing works. Cant find where is the connectin between tomcat and oracle..Where to grant something to tomcat user on oracle tables? Just found that im connecting using some username and granted priviledges to him. If i try to insert via wsf-t into another table that was created by user 'map' -everything works fine. The 'SETTLEMENTS' table was imported into oracle from shapefile before i was given the preinstalled geoserver/oracle server.

Comment: Can you, please, show how to grant persmissions on the needed tables to the user who is running geoserver?

Comment: Seems that i have THIS: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gis.geoserver.user/21492 problem.

Answer (score 1):

Something to note:  Geoserver's (v2.10.1) layer security caused my read only exception.  For my Development instance I removed all layer security by updating the default line:

`*.*.w=ADMIN,GROUP_ADMIN`

to

`*.*.w=*`

in the file data_dir\security\layer.properties(Not recommended for any environment but your sandpit).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The same error occurs if the table has a timestamp (using Oracle db). Doing it without a timestamp solved the problem.